# AWS - Glue sources (or custom sources) addition

Tags: aws-glue

I'm working on an extraction from Google Analytics 4 using Glue jobs so I've checked the list of sources provided by default in Glue and I couldn't find such source, nevertheless I was thinking about creating it for the account I'm using and I couldn't find the appropriated docs about how to do so, if possible at all.

So I would like to know how to create a source to a web-API (or any other source) that then is shown on the mentioned list. Right now I'm running a Python script using glue to do it so the closet approach would be to create a boilerplate code, which is not what I'm asking for. Thanks all in advance.

[image]